# Processing a 2D Array Diagonally

Tags: java, arrays

I'm working on a Cipher project for my computer science class, and we are supposed to put a string into a square 2D array, filling remaining spaces with asterisks, and then print out an encoded message by traversing the array diagonally.

For example, with a message "testcipher," the array would be

[t, e, s, t]

[c, i, p, h]

[e, r, *, *]

[*, *, *, *]

And the array would be processed to give "t i * * e p * * s h e * t c r *"

I could really use some help with this. Thanks in advance!

Comment: tiepshetcr or tiepshtecr ?

Comment: Sorry there are supposed to be asterisks. I put that back in.

Comment: Show us what have you tried?

Comment: Honestly I have no idea where to start. I would imagine that a nested for-loop would be used and the index values would just be reset if it got too high.

Comment: Just take a pencil and paper and write down every step. What happens with the indices. Try to found a pattern in it. When you exactly know what's happening, try to code it.

Answer (score 1):

Let's take it step by step:

1) We need to find the dimension of the 2D array. Since it has to be squared we have to find the first squared number greater or equal to the length of the string.

*small edit:* I assume cipher is a String.

```
int arrayDimension = 0;
while (arrayDimension * arrayDimension < cipher.length())
{
    arrayDimension++;
}
```

2) Now we place the cipher character by character in the array.

```
int currentCharacterIndex = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < arrayDimension; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < arrayDimension; j++)
    {
        if (currentCharacterIndex < cipher.length()) 
            array[i][j] = cipher.charAt(currentCharacterIndex++);
        else
            array[i][j] = '*';
    }
}
```

This could be simplified I guess, but the purpose of this bit of code is for you to understand the idea and hopefully write a better version.

3) We have our array so the easiest thing to do is SHIFT all rows (except for the first one) to the left *rowIndex* times.

So basically for a row of `c i p h` we'll end up with `i p h c`. As a result, we now have to print each column and our job here is done.

The code should look like this (it's pretty simple so I'll leave this to you):

```
//Shift each row
char firstColumnChar;
for (int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < arrayDimension; rowIndex++)
{
    //We shift rowIndex times
    for (int timesToShift = rowIndex; timesToShift > 0; timesToShift--)
    {
        firstColumnChar = array[rowIndex][0]; //We keep the first char in some variable
        //We shift all elements to the left - except for the first one
        for (int i = 0; i < rowIndex - 1; i++)
            array[rowIndex][i] = array[rowIndex][i+1];

        //We now shift the first character to the last column
        array[rowIndex][arrayDimension - 1] = firstColumnChar;
    }
}

//Print columns
for (int columnIndex = 0; columnIndex < arrayDimension; columnIndex++)
{
    for (int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < arrayDimension; rowIndex++)
        System.out.print(array[rowIndex][columnIndex] + " ");
    //You can print a '\n' here if you want to
}
```

Comment: Awesome! exactly what I was thinking.

Comment: One thing to note: youre first while loop could be confusing, as it implies that arrayDimension==cipher.length(); perhaps add something including the squared in the code?

Comment: Thank you very much! This makes it much easier. Sorry to say though, but I'm having trouble shifting it rowIndex times. Could you give me a hint as to what to do?

Comment: also I had already set the array up so I only needed the third step

Comment: Thank you @BenKnoble for correcting me, I completely forgot to use the squared value for the arrayDimension.

Comment: @DavisFridleyTheSpookyScary I completed the code for the last step and added some comments, I hope it's all clear now. The trick is to take each element and shift it to the left once. Since you can't put the first column character on position -1, you will save it in another separate char. After you shift all other columns you put the saved character on the last column. Just like the basic shifting of an array (the one-dimensional one).